# Hide the text if text is displaying outside container

Tags: javascript, css, html

We are displaying text by fetching json....

Onclick Text, We are allowing user to add more text....

[image]

**Issue** :

Added text should display only inside container , if text reaches beyond the container, then it should be hiden as [this 5 seconds video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10LFDyK8K7MnuPRq_jMCHfs4YmY-ZSdRf/view) , but now text is displaying beyond the container as in below code....

```js
let jsonData = {   
    
    "layers": [{
        "x": 0,
        "height": 300,
        "layers": [                      
            {
                "justification": "center",
                "font": "Coustard-Black",
                "x": 190,
                "y": 150,
                "src": "0a7fb3015bb19745da114bc581e96947_Font248.ttf",
                "width": 72,
                "type": "text",
                "color": "red",
                "size": 32,
                "text": "DATE",
                "height": 17,
                "name": "edit_date"
            }
        ],
        "y": 0,
        "width": 300,
        "type": "group",
        "name": "fb_post_4"
    }]
};

const containerElement = $('#container');
const fileUp = $('#fileup');

$(function() {   

    // IGNORE BELOW CODE

    //  Fetch text from json file

    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y,
                    height: layer.height,
                    width: layer.width,
                    name: layer.name
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y,
                        height,
                        width,
                        name
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y),
                            height,
                            width,
                            name: (name)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }

    function json(data)

    {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;

        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;
        let counter = 0;
        let table = [];

        // container dimensions
        containerElement.css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');
        //end

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y,
                name
            } of arr) {
                   
            var imageUrl1 = '';                         
            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                imageUrl: imageUrl1,

                // Fetch Mask images
                maskImageUrl: 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + src,
                // end

                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                    // Mask image positions
                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                    // end
                },
                id: counter
            });
            table.push(mask);
            fileup.onchange = function() {

                let mask2 = table[target];
                const newImageLoadedId = mask2.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup.files[0]));
                document.getElementById('fileup').value = "";               
            };
            counter++;
        }

        // Text
        drawText(data);
    }
    json(jsonData);
}); // end of function

// IGNORE ABOVE CODE

//Fetch text

const fonts = []; // caching duplicate fonts

function drawText(layer) {

    if (layer.type === 'image') return;

    if (!layer.type || layer.type === 'group') {
        return layer.layers.forEach(drawText)
    }

    if (layer.type === 'text') {
        const url = 'https://i.imgur.com/' + layer.src;

        if (!fonts.includes(url)) {
            fonts.push(url);
            $("style").prepend("@font-face {\n" +
                "\tfont-family: \"" + layer.font + "\";\n" +
                "\tsrc: url(" + url + ") format('truetype');\n" +
                "}");
        }

        // Below is text Code
        const lightId = 'light' + layer.name
        const lightIdString = '#' + lightId
        $('.container').append(
            '<input id="font" style="display:none"><a id ="' + layer.name + '" ' +
            '<div class="txtContainer" id = "text" contenteditable="true" ' +
            'style="' +
            'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' +
            'font-size: ' + layer.size + 'px; ' +
            '">' + layer.text + '</div></a>' +
            '<div id="light' + layer.name + '" class="white_content" style="' +
            'left: ' + layer.x + 'px; ' +
            'top: ' + layer.y + 'px; ' + '"> ' +            
            '</div> <div>'
        );            
    }

}
// text end

// IGNORE BELOW CODE 

(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        
        container.updateStyle = function() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                    resolve();
                };
            });
        };        
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.container {
 background: silver;
 position: relative;
}

.container img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 250px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: 999;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

.txtContainer {
 position: absolute;
 color: #FFF;
 white-space: pre;
}

.txtContainer:hover {
 position: absolute;
 background: red;
 white-space: pre;
}

.pip {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body style="background : green">
<input id="fileup" name="fileup" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div id="container"class="container">
</div>
```

Here is [Codepen](https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/WWaZKb)

Comment: just use `overflow:hidden` in `container div`

Comment: change your css with this `.white_content {
 display: none;
 width: 70%;
 height: 40%;
 padding: 16px;
 border: 16px solid orange;
 background-color: white;
 z-index: 1002;
 overflow: auto;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to the `.container`.

```css
.container {
    background: silver;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: thanks, it worked fine, but there is issue if we use `overflow:hidden` , when user click on text, we are displaying pop_up also , that pop up will not display completly..... [codepen](https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/eoPeNG)

Comment: Try to move the popup outside the container. On line 334: use `$('.container').after(/*...*/)` instead of `$('.container').append(/*...*/)`

Comment: sorry for delay, i followed your code , now i can't able to see `dropdown` which will help to change font-size....  [ https://imgur.com/a/SnIQ3PO ] , before i was seeing dropdown.... also text will not hide now beyond container,

Comment: but in [this link](https://www.greetingsisland.com/design/invitations/surrealism-balloons/201-14150) , it working fine.....

Comment: Eh.. I don't want to dive too deep into your code. Probably you have lost some references moving the popup anywhere else then before. But what you need is to have the text input inside a container, which has `overflow: hidden` and the popup outside of it. If you look at the working site, you will see, that they did it exactly like that. The other issues are probably javascript related.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong markup

```
<a id="edit_date" <div="" class="txtContainer" contenteditable="true" style="left: 190px; top: 150px; font-size: 32px; ">DAdTE</a>
```